# How to create Java REPL with Java.exe and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, jquery, read-eval-print-loop

I want to create **Java REPL** Web Application so I need to know any techniques and ideas for it

so I need your help, you can see some images that is C# Intractive Shell (I need Java like)

http://csharppad.com/
seems this created by jQueryUI & C# compiler !!!

[image]

1. How can I have intelisense like that ? (javascript autocomplete ???)
2. How can I fetch keywords with types (method,class,interface,...) for intellisense ? (current and new libraries)

[image]

3. How can I have realtime error checking ?

[image]

4. How Can I have Documentation in my intelisense ? (current and new libraries)

4.1. Can I fetch them from javadocs ?

[image]

5. How can I get all method overloads like that ?

5.1. Can I fetch them from javadocs too ?

[image]

Can anybody help me for develop something like this ?

I need your ideas because I don't know how start and which libraries must have ?

Answer (score 0):

I think they have already created something like this here:
https://github.com/lorenzoongithub/nudge4j

using the browser you get a web console where you can write nashorn/javascript to manipulate the java objects in your running JVM.